# StackoverflowError while inflating Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I have some weird Stackoverflowerror which is thrown in the onCreateView() method of a Fragment i use.

[image]

As you can see in this image, that is the method where it breaks. The First TODO should be where the error comes from.

[image]

I have no idea what could be wrong with that line:

```
  view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_chat, container, false); //it breaks here
```

I would be very glad to hear any tipps from anyone.

Edit: this is another strange errorreport i got after the initial error:

[image]

Edit: Content of Activity_chat.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/msg_list"
        android:name="com.example.f00.mobileapp.listener.TabFragment2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/tab_fragment_2" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/send_btn"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Send" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/msg_edit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/send_btn"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/send_btn"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Edit: TabFragment2.java:

```
package com.example.f00.mobileapp.listener;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.f00.mobileapp.R;
import com.example.f00.mobileapp.activities.MainActivity;
import com.example.f00.mobileapp.application.Common;
import com.example.f00.mobileapp.fragments.EditContactDialog;
import com.example.f00.mobileapp.fragments.MessagesFragment;
import com.example.f00.mobileapp.utils.AsyncResponse;
import com.example.f00.mobileapp.utils.DataProvider;
import com.example.f00.mobileapp.utils.GcmUtil;
import com.example.f00.mobileapp.utils.Utils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

// Chat chat real chat.

public class TabFragment2 extends Fragment implements MessagesFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
    EditContactDialog.OnFragmentInteractionListener, View.OnClickListener {

    View view;

    private EditText msgEdit;
    private Button sendBtn;
    private String profileId;
    private String profileName;
    private String profileEmail;
    private GcmUtil gcmUtil;

    public Context context;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_2, container, false); //TODO this it where it breaks

//////////////
        profileId = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra(Common.PROFILE_ID);
        msgEdit = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.msg_edit);
        sendBtn = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.send_btn);
        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        android.app.ActionBar actionBar =  getActivity().getActionBar(); //TODO
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(Uri.withAppendedPath(DataProvider.CONTENT_URI_PROFILE, profileId), null, null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            profileName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DataProvider.COL_NAME));
            profileEmail = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DataProvider.COL_EMAIL));
            actionBar.setTitle(profileName);
        }
        actionBar.setSubtitle("connecting ...");

        getActivity().registerReceiver(registrationStatusReceiver, new IntentFilter(Common.ACTION_REGISTER));
        gcmUtil = new GcmUtil(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        ///////////
        return view;

    }

/*
    /**
     * The important piece of code is in onCreate() where we instantiate GcmUtil.
     * This triggers registration with GCM if it's not already done.
     * Recall that GcmUtil broadcasts the registration status which this activity
     * registers to listen.
     *
     * @param savedInstanceState
     */

   /* @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);


        getActivity().getIntent().getStringArrayExtra(Common.PROFILE_ID);
        profileId = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra(Common.PROFILE_ID);
        msgEdit = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.msg_edit);
        sendBtn = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.send_btn);
        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Uri.withAppendedPath(DataProvider.CONTENT_URI_PROFILE, profileId), null, null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            profileName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DataProvider.COL_NAME));
            profileEmail = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DataProvider.COL_EMAIL));
            actionBar.setTitle(profileName);
        }
        actionBar.setSubtitle("connecting ...");

        registerReceiver(registrationStatusReceiver, new IntentFilter(Common.ACTION_REGISTER));
        gcmUtil = new GcmUtil(getApplicationContext());


    }*/

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.


        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.chat, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_edit:
                EditContactDialog dialog = new EditContactDialog();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString(Common.PROFILE_ID, profileId);
                args.putString(DataProvider.COL_NAME, profileName);
                dialog.setArguments(args);
                dialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "EditContactDialog");
                return true;

            case android.R.id.home:
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.send_btn:
                send(msgEdit.getText().toString());
                msgEdit.setText(null);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEditContact(String name) {
        getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(name); //TODO
    }

    @Override
    public String getProfileEmail() {
        return profileEmail;
    }

    /**
     * Finally to send a message we post the data to our server asynchronously.
     *
     * @param txt
     */
    private void send(final String txt) {

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {

                    Utils sendMsg = new Utils(new AsyncResponse() {

                        @Override
                        public void asyncResponse(Object output, boolean status) {
                        }
                    });

                    //TODO
                    sendMsg.sendChatMessage(System.identityHashCode(new Random()), txt, getActivity().getApplicationContext());


      /*              ServerUtilities.send(txt, profileEmail);
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(2);
                    values.put(DataProvider.COL_TYPE, DataProvider.MessageType.OUTGOING.ordinal());
                    values.put(DataProvider.COL_MESSAGE, txt);
                    values.put(DataProvider.COL_RECEIVER_EMAIL, profileEmail);
                    values.put(DataProvider.COL_SENDER_EMAIL, Common.getPreferredEmail());
                    values.put(DataProvider.COL_ID, System.currentTimeMillis());
                    getContentResolver().insert(DataProvider.CONTENT_URI_MESSAGES, values);
*/
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Message could not be sent";
                }

                return msg;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(msg)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }

    public void sendNewOrder(final String text) {
        //TODO
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(1);
        values.put(DataProvider.COL_COUNT, 0);
        getActivity().getContentResolver().update(Uri.withAppendedPath(DataProvider.CONTENT_URI_PROFILE, profileId), values, null, null);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(registrationStatusReceiver);
        gcmUtil.cleanup();
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    /**
     *
     */

    { }
    private BroadcastReceiver registrationStatusReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent != null && Common.ACTION_REGISTER.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                switch (intent.getIntExtra(Common.EXTRA_STATUS, 100)) {
                    case Common.STATUS_SUCCESS:
                       getActivity().getActionBar().setSubtitle("online");
                        break;

                    case Common.STATUS_FAILED:
                        getActivity().getActionBar().setSubtitle("offline");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: you should probably add code instead of images so that others can also try with that piece of code

Comment: what's the content of activity_chat.xml?

Comment: Did your try with pressing Sync project with gradle files button?

Comment: `TabFragment2` inflates itself over and over

Comment: Does com.example.f00.mobileapp.listener.TabFragment2 contain an instance of the activity_chat.xml layout? Looks like you are getting a circular dependency between the layout and the Fragment.

Comment: no, it does not. what do you mean an instance? how can i instantiate a xml? TabFragment2 is the fragment that is defined by activity_chat.xml.

Comment: Hi, can you please include the XML for the layout `tab_fragment_2`.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla it already is, sorry for the naming inconvenience: it is chat_activity.xml (though it is no activity)

Comment: No, you should have an XML file in your layout folder called `tab_fragment_2` which you reference here: `tools:layout="@layout/tab_fragment_2"` - Please add the XML to your question as well so we can examine it. The `inflate` call should also point to `tab_fragment_2` and not `activity_chat`

Comment: this is the same file, i renamed it. sorry :-/

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing a lot of things in your `onCreateView` - My recommendation is that you move the rest of the code in the `onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)`. Change the `onCreateView` into:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {      
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_chat, container, false);     
        return rootView;
    }
```

Then you can **move the rest of the code to `onActivityCreated`**. This method is called after the `onCreateView()` method when the host activity is created. 
 Activity and fragment instance have been created as well as the view hierarchy of the activity. At this point, view can be accessed with the `findViewById()` method.

Comment: Cool, I am glad it helped. Please accept the answer so that your question can be marked as answered. Enjoy.